# Reading and manipulating a WAV file in C++

Tags: c++, audio

I'm trying to write a simple program to read a WAV file in C++ and get data like sample rate and bit depth. At some point I want to use this to manipulate the data to create an audio plugin, but I want to understand this first.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <ostream>
using namespace std;

struct wavfile {
    char   id[4];
    int    totallength;
    char   wavefmt[8];
    int    format;
    short  pcm;
    short  channels;
    int    frequency;
    int    bytes_per_second;
    short  bytes_by_capture;
    short  bits_per_sample;
    char   data[4];
    int    bytes_in_data;
};

int main () {
    FILE * wfile;
    std::ofstream ofs;
    wfile = ofs.open("tes.wav",std::ofstream::binary | std::ofstream::app); // line 31

    ofs.close();

return 0;
}
```

When I try to run it it keep saying "assigning to 'FILE *' (aka '__sFILE *') from incompatible type 'void'"

How can I get it to open the wave file, read the data, so I can define it as a within the struct wavfile and print it back out?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, even just pointing me in the right direction or to a good resource. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hello, `std::ofstream::open` returns void so you cannot set the value of a variable using its return value. More over `std::ofsteam` is an out file stream so you cannot read things from it. I think you're looking for `std::ifstream` (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/read/). And you don't need one of your variable, why do you have a `FILE*` and an `std::ofstream`? If you want to read your file, either use `std::ifstream` which belongs the C++ standard library or use `FILE` which belongs to C library but not both in the same time.

Comment: What manual are you working from?